# Backbone.Marionette Layout + Region + View inserts an extra element, breaking Bootstrap styles

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, marionette

I'm running into a problem getting Backbone.Marionette to cooperate with Twitter Bootstrap. Bootstrap expects markup to conform to predefined patterns in order to work, but the way that Backbone and Marionette handle things, it seems to be impossible to use a `Marionette.Layout` to generate Bootstrap-compliant markup for a navbar with an embedded dropdown.

Here's the problem:

Let's say I have a `Marionette.Layout` representing the navbar, and I want to have a `region`, where I will put the `CollectionView` or `CompositeView` that manages the items in the dropdown. The `region` is a selector, so in this case if we have:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Static item</li>
    <li id="dynamic-dropdown"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then the Layout would specify the region for the dynamic dropdown as follows:

```
Marionette.Layout.extend({
  regions: {
    dropdown: '#dynamic-dropdown'
  }
...
});
```

I would then have a `CompositeView` that takes care of rendering the dropdown item models, specifies the extra markup for the Bootstrap dropdown, and so forth. The problem is that it appears to be impossible to make `#dynamic-dropdown` be the `$el` for the `CompositeView`, as Backbone always inserts an extra `div` (or whatever you specify in `tagName`). In order for the dropdown to appear as expected, I need to get rid of that extra element and have the view's root be `#dynamic-dropdown`.

[I've put together a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7auhR/5/) illustrating what I mean.

tl;dr How do I make a `View`'s root element be the region specified in a `Marionette.Layout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the markup that is generated in the end follows the same as required by Bootstrap (use the console to debug).

The required markup is as follows:

[image]

The markup generated by your code has the following problems:

[image]

So, to fix it you have to change your `nav` template to:

```
<script type="text/html" id="nav">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav" id="dropdown">
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

And your views to render `<li>` instead of `<div>`

```
var DropdownItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     tagName: 'li',
     template: "#dropdown-item"
});

var DropdownView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#dropdown-collection",
    className: 'dropdown',
    tagName: 'li',
    itemView: DropdownItem,
    itemViewContainer: '#dropdown-items'
});
```

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/7auhR/6/

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Now let's say I wanted to add more navigation items to the `<ul class="nav">` -- in your solution it appears that only a single `DropdownView` can be added to that region rather than multiple items, which one would expect in a navbar. I'm having a look at `Backbone.Babysitter` which looks like it might solve that issue.